# How to activate a php if statement with a jQuery ui draggable?

Tags: php, jquery, css, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm having a div layer which should be moved to the right or left and when its moved far enough I want it to run a php statement ( Div 500px to right activates $state = 1;)

This is what I got so far:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.swipe').draggable({
        axis :'x', revert:true, revertDuration:'250',
    });
});
</script>
```

This is my Div:

```
<div id="middleLayerShadow" class="swipe">... some stuff (pics and so on)...</div>
```

and the head part of the website:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="javascript/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

I want the div to go back like I programmed it with (revert:true) and when its dragged and drop at a far enough distance to left or to right i want it to disappear and somehow let a variable in php register it :)

Imagine it like a Tinder rating field where you swipe left and right!
Please help ! :)

Comment: Where is the PHP code in this? Anyway, PHP is server-side. When jQuery executes, PHP is out of scope. If you want to «register» anything using PHP (and probably a database), you have to use ajax.

Comment: that's the thing i dont know where to add/start with php but ok i'll look into this ajax thing :) @LouysPatriceBessette

Comment: You have to write a stand-alone PHP scrip that does what you need, then you need to write a `$.ajax` function on drag/drop that calls the php script